# A Struts 1.3 application:enforcing a timestamp passing parameter with every URL

Tags: sessiontracking

I would like to enforce a dynamic parameter (time-stamp) with every url of the application

I would like to use this parameter to solve the iterative problem of invoking the browser back button or a url from the history by comparing the current page time-stamp with the invoked URL time-stamp.

Any clue is Highly appreciated

Hossam Khalil

Comment: Do not edit answers to reply to them--leave a comment or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

What's the "current page timestamp"? Do you mean by checking against the server's current time?

You'd need to have a timestamp in every link, which could be done with a custom tag.

Each form would need a timestamp, which could also be done via custom tag.

A custom request processor would be the Struts 1-way, although you may just be able to use a filter.

You may need to provide more details regarding what *exact* problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: May be my approach is not the optimal